# Profile activity page does not adapt when viewing the full site on mobile

Tags: bug, profile-page, design, activity-tab

The user profile Activity page does not adapt to a mobile view like the rest of the site. I'm not sure if this is by design or a bug, but as it doesn't conform to the rest of the mobile experience I'm starting by tagging this with [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug). Screenshot below:

[image: Profile Activity view]

Conversely, the main profile page looks as one would expect with an adaptive view:

[image: Main profile page]

Comment: It's coming, just not here yet! See [Aaron's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1238302) under the [responsive profile announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370964): "*Both the Settings and Activity sections are being worked on now and will have a similar aesthetic [to the redesigned profile page]. Settings is way closer. ...*"

Comment: much worse is that mobile you can choose then name by adding a character to an @